# Using TikZ to draw a relation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I wanted to know how to make this drawing of a relation R in a set A. I've searched around a little but I don't find what I need. Thanks in advance! Sorry I don't know much of TikZ.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What have you tried so far? Please provide a minimal working example of your current attempt. You might be able to use the state transitions defined in the `automata` TikZ library for the relationships - the nodes itself should be rather straightforward.

Comment: I tried searching "tikz automata" and I found some interesting links. Thanks for your comment. Tomorrow I'm going to keep trying. Unfortunately I don't know TikZ very well so I couldn't try much

Comment: I was going to recommend using dot2tex, but I forgot how to create a circular reference like what you've shown in dot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With circular loops and bent arrows. This can be achieved by using an `arc` in some `to path` construction.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,calc}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[carrow/.style={to path={%
    ($(\tikztotarget)+(#1:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cradius})+(#1+170:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cradius})$)
    arc[start angle=#1+170,end angle=#1-170,radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cradius}]},
    ->},dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1.2pt,fill,outer sep=0.5ex},
    cradius/.initial=0.4,
    >={Latex[bend]},bend angle=12]
 \path node[dot,label=225:{$a$}](a){}
  ++ (45:1.5) node[dot,label=45:{$b$}](b){}
  ++ (-30:1.5) node[dot,label=90:{$c$}](c){}
  ($(a)+(0,-1.8)$) node[dot,label=225:{$d$}](d){}
  ++ (1.5,0.1) node[dot,label=225:{$f$}](f){}
  ++ (1.5,-0.3) node[dot,label=-120:{$e$}](e){}
  ++ (0:1.8) node[dot,label=-60:{$h$}](h){}
  ++ (120:1.8) node[dot,label=90:{$g$}](g){};
 \path[shorten >=1ex, shorten <=0.5ex,semithick] 
 (a) edge[->,bend left] (b) edge[carrow=45] (b)
 (b) edge[->,bend left] (a) edge[carrow=-135,<-] (a)
 edge[carrow=-135,<-] (d)
 edge[carrow=-135,<-] (f)
 edge[carrow=-120] (e)
 edge[carrow=-60,<-] (h)
 edge[carrow=90,<-] (g)
 edge[carrow=90,<-] (c)
 (e) edge[->,bend left] (g)
 (g) edge[->,bend left] (e)
 (h) edge[->,bend left] (g)
 (g) edge[->,bend left] (h)
 (e) edge[->,bend left] (h)
 (h) edge[->,bend left] (e);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful result!

Answer (score 6):

Part of your image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                > = Stealth,
    node distance = 22mm,
every edge/.style = {->, draw, thick, bend angle=15},
every label/.style= {inner sep=1pt, font=\small},   
       dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=1mm}
                        ]
\node (a) [dot,label=above:a] {};
\draw (a) edge[out=225, in=315, looseness=9] (a);
%
\node (b) [dot,label=below:b, right=of a] {};
\draw (b) edge[out=225, in=315, looseness=9] (b);
%
\node (c) [dot,label=below:c, right=of b] {};
\node (d) [dot,label=above:d, above right=of c] {};
\node (e) [dot,label=below:e, below right=of d] {};
\draw (c) edge[out=225, in=315, looseness=9] (c)
      (c) edge[bend right] (d)
      (d) edge[bend right] (c)
      (d) edge[out=135, in= 45, looseness=9] (d)
      (d) edge[bend right] (e)
      (e) edge[bend right] (d)
      (e) edge[out=225, in=315, looseness=9] (e)
      (e) edge[bend right] (c)
      (c) edge[bend right] (e);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For other loop directions you need to select appropriate `out` and `in` angles.